# parse json android and show it in textview

Tags: android, json

I am new to android developing, my website returns posts with following format in json:

```
post= {
'artist':'xxxx',
'title':'xxxx',
'text':'xxxx',
'url':'http://xxxx'
}
```

I know something about receiving a file from the net and saving it to a SD card, but I want to do it on fly, parse it and show in on some text view, can you please give me some simple code for this?

I tried searching but I can't find a good tutorial for this, so this is the last place I'm coming to solve my problem.

Comment: your json seems to invalid. can you check if its valid @ http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: May be your json should be `"artist":"xxxx",`

Answer (score 0):

A good framework for parsing XML is [Google's GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Basically you could deserialize your XML as follows (`import` statements left out):

```
public class Post {
   private String artist, title, text, url;

   public Post() {} // No args constructor.
}

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Gson gson = new Gson();

     String jsonString = readFromNetwork(); // Read JSON from network...

     Post post = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Post.class);

     // Use post instance populated with your JSON data.
   }
}
```

Read more in [GSON's user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).